# Migration Assist tool not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

While conversion of IBM Mobilefirst Platform 7.0 hybrid source code to IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0 source code using mfpmigrate assist tool, I am getting an error as follows:

```
C:\Mobilefirst>mfpmigrate client --in C:\Mobilefirst\Example --out C:\Mobilefirst\CordovaNewCode
Error: An error occured during execution of command.
Error: Option '--in' cannot be equal to option '--out'
```

Also, if I am using `scan` then it says `No deprecated or not supported APIs found.`. Even though I have used old API as mentioned for IBM Mobilefirst Platform 7.1 and below versions.

```
C:\Mobilefirst>mfpmigrate scan --in C:\Mobilefirst\Example --out C:\Mobilefirst\CordovaNewCode
Starting the process to detect deprecated and not supported APIs...
Getting files from C:\Mobilefirst\...
Scanning C:\Mobilefirst\...
No deprecated or not supported APIs found.
Process to detect deprecated and not supported APIs has completed.
```

Please let me know why it is not converting hybrid to cordova IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0.

Thanks,

Comment: May be there are no deprecated API's in your code. Can you mention any old API you feel that you use in your project which are deprecated and the tool does not identify it during "scan".

Comment: Re: '--in cannot be equal to option --out' - have you tried pointing to a completely different directory outside of the main directory path from --in? e.g. C:\Mobilefirst_2\CordovaNewCode?

Comment: @deepak, can you provide an example project - say share it via dropbox or any other file sharing service

Comment: Error: An error occured during execution of command.
Error: No supported platforms were detected to migrate

Comment: I have tried with different directory location and it gives response "No supported platforms were detected to migrate".
cmd snippet:
C:\Mobilefirst>mfpmigrate client --in C:\Mobilefirst\Example --out D:\CordProj
Error: An error occured during execution of command.
Error: No supported platforms were detected to migrate
For "scan", error is still the same "No deprecated or not supported APIs found."
I have added below line of code that have been deprecated in MobileFirst 8.0
var devName=WL.Device.getFriendlyName();

Comment: Do you have any environments added to your project?

Comment: If environments added or not, it gives same error: Error: An error occured during execution of command. Error: No supported platforms were detected to migrate

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation, you must point to the actual app folder, e.g. ../Desktop/InvokingAdapterProcedures/apps/InvokingAdapterProcedures, and that app must also have environments such as iPhone or Android. Otherwise it will complain about missing environments.

See:  https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/#classic-hybrid-applications